# printing in a row with parentheses in c

Tags: c, printing

I need your help.
I need to print a binary tree in order- that way:

if I have only one node print: (3)

if I insert to this tree a node 2- it will print: ((2)<(3))

if I insert to this tree a node 7- it will print: ((2)<(3)>(7))

if I insert to this tree a node 6- it will print: ((2)<(3)>((6)<(7)))

if I insert to this tree a node 9- it will print: ((2)<(3)>((6)<(7)>(9)))

I need to print this in recursion and I got lost with the parentheses 
someone has an idea or a clue to this ?

thanks (:

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because there's no attempt at showing a solution to the task with a question about why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an in-order operation.

- If your current node has any children, print `(`.
- If there's a left child, print its structure; then `<`.
- Print the current node in parentheses.
- If there's a right child, print `>` and then print its structure.
- If the current node has any children, print ')'.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for inorder binary tree traversal.
Take a look on the code, and add parentheses and angle brackets `<>` when needed.

```
 void inorder(struct tree *root)
 {
   if(root != NULL)
   {
     inorder(root->left);
     printf(" %d",root->info);
     inorder(root->right);
   }
   return;
 }
```

[tree traversal in c](http://www.engineersgarage.com/c-language-programs/perform-tree-operations-insert-traversal-preorderpost-order-and-order)